# Is it safe to gnome-session-quit && shutdown -h now?

Tags: partition, encryption, io, luks, cryptsetup

I have a LUKS external partition that is automatically opened/mounted and closed/unmounted by pam_mount during login and logout. Right now I am having to log out in the terminal and then shutdown using the GUI at the login screen.

I want to write an alias for the command `gnome-session-quit && shutdown -h now` to make this quick and easy but I don't know if this would affect the LUKS partition in any way if I don't give it enough time to gracefully unmount and close. I don't want to boot into a session where my encrypted drive fails to work because this command crashed it while it was still doing I/O operations.

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown *will* wait for disks to be unmounted. See https://serverfault.com/questions/327758/linux-graceful-shutdown or https://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/shutdown.html

The command you've posted will shutdown without data loss from filesystem corruption.

Comment: So the command will work? Thats good to know, now I can make an alias for it. Your link does ay that shutdown is graceful, but it doesn't address whether pam_mount will still close the LUKS encrypted drive.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia if the partition is cleanly `umount`'ed, it shouldn't matter whether or not it gets a `luksClose` since that doesn't do any writing to the drive itself anyway.

Comment: thanks @Xen2050. Do you think I should set a timer in between the log off and shutdown, in order to ensure the partition is cleanly unmounted, e.g. `gnome-session-quit && shutdown -h 1`? Or is a delay not necessary in your opinion.

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia I'm not sure what gnome-session-quit umounts, but shutdown should be doing safe umounting anyway. Unless you're seeing errors (like dirty filesystems) I probably wouldn't bother with a delay, but if it's just a few seconds that might not be a big deal either

Answer (score 0):

No it is not safe to `gnome-session-quit && shutdown -h now`.

For example, if you have unsaved work, say a modified text document in a gedit window, Gnome will display a dialog warning you of unsaved work and show *Cancel* and *Logout* buttons. The dialog says you "will be logged out automatically in 60 seconds." The `gnome-session-quit` command, however, returns immediately with an exit status code of `0`. Thus the `shutdown -h now` command will execute immediately; the system will shutdown without giving you the opportunity to cancel the logout action to save your unsaved work.